# RMarkdown Generate A List

Tags: knitr, r-markdown

How do I take a data frame and produce a list of values from a data frame as a list.

Like if I had a data frame declared like `na.omit(input$Comments)` how would I get each of the values to be output as bullet points for that block?

The data specified is like paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I've been doing similar things and no one has answered it. This is how I solved this problem:

````
```{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis', eval = TRUE}
exp <- as.data.frame(c("this", "is", "a", "test"))
exp <- apply(exp, 1, function(x) paste("* ", x, "\n"))
for(x in exp){cat(x)}
```
````

This should yield a bulleted list like:

> - this
> - is
> - a
> - test

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse solution to this question:

````
```{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}

library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

exp <- 
  enframe(c("this", "is", "a", "test"), value = "var", name = NULL) %>% 
  mutate(var = paste("* ", var, "\n")) %>% 
  walk(cat)


```
````